# "That's what I said!"

Tags: dialogue, the-goonies

All throughout the movie *The Goonies* a character will say something wrong and then say "That's what I said!" For example Data says "bootie" trap instead of "boobie" trap and then say's "That's what I said!" Mikey, Chunk, Mouth, and the mom all say it at least once in the movie. 
I was just wondering what (if there's any) significance this line has to the movie.

Comment: I think it's just a running gag.

Comment: I reckon @TrishLing is right, it's just a running gag in the film, maybe it was even an in-joke with the writers. I definitely don't think it has any sexual connotations as is suggested in the answer below.

Comment: "That's *delude yourself*, dummy." [*Goonies* - dictate myself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4db7r6kXi4), YouTube

Answer (score 12):

The line is spoken by three people -- Chunk, Mikey, and Mikey's mother -- and **in each case, the dialogue helps develop each person's character**:

- Chunk says it twice, out of frustration when people don't listen to him, suggesting he is often ignored
- Mikey says it three times, as a cover-up for when he had previously mispronounced something, suggesting he can't admit when he is wrong
- Mikey's mom says it once, also as a cover-up, suggesting that Mikey picked up the tendency from her

---

> Chunk: (His mouth still full) Do you think your Mom's going to notice...notice that the dick and balls are missing?
>
> Mikey: I wonder if she'll notice.
>
> Chunk: That's what I said!
>
> ---
>
> Brand: It's the Fratellis.
>
> Data: That's the guy from upstairs.
>
> Mikey: And the guy who tried to sing.
>
> Chunk: See, you guys, you never listen to me. I said that there was going to
>   be trouble, but you didn't listen to me.
>
> ---
>
> Mikey: And they were digging all these tunnels, and caves. Setting boody traps.
>
> Data: Booby traps.
>
> Mikey: That's what I said.
>
> ---
>
> Mikey: He's going to give it back to the museum, or whoever they pick to be
>   the new assistant curly, or kerney...
>
> Brand: Curator.
>
> Mikey: That's what I said.
>
> ---
>
> Mikey: They did a show. It was a retropackum, and it was a...
>
> Brand: Retrospective.
>
> Mikey: That's what I said. You always contradict me.
>
> ---
>
> Irene: Brandon, don't you come home without your brother, or I'll commit
>   hare... Hare Krishna!
>
> Brand: That's "Hara-Kiri," Ma.
>
> Irene: That's exactly what I said.